# How to use pandas to find the most occuring item in list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, word-frequency

I have a list of fruits

```
fruits=["Apple","Mango","Orange","Apple","Mango"
```

I'm trying to use the pandas module to find the most occuring fruits. I want it to print both apple and Mango

Comment: why do you need pandas for that ? you can do it without pandas

Comment: @jimmar I did some digging and that's only method I found that was able to print out the most frequent even though there are more than one

Comment: If there's any shorter or easier way other than with pandas that's would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other methods to generate a counter from a list, but since you asked for pandas there is `value_counts`.

Edit For ties:

```
import pandas as pd

fruits=["Apple","Mango","Orange","Apple","Mango"]
counts = pd.Series(fruits).value_counts().to_dict()
max_val = max(counts.items(), key=lambda x : x[1])
max_keys=[]
for key, value in counts.items():
    if value == max_val[1]:
        max_keys.append(key)
print(max_keys)
```

Output:

```
['Apple', 'Mango']
```